# Equivalence between Subscript Notation and Pointer Dereferencing

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array, malloc, dereference

It is more than one questions. I need to deal with an NxN  matrix A of integers in C. How can I allocate the memory in the heap? Is this correct?

```
int **A=malloc(N*sizeof(int*));
for(int i=0;i<N;i++) *(A+i)= malloc(N*sizeof(int));
```

I am not absolutely sure if the second line of the above code should be there to initiate the memory.

Next, suppose I want to access the element A[i, j] where i and j are the row and column indices starting from zero. It it possible to do it via dereferencing the pointer **A somehow? For example, something like *(A+n*i+j)? I know I have some conceptual gap here and some help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> not absolutely sure if the second line of the above code should be there to initiate the memory.

It needs to be there, as it actually allocates the space for the `N` rows carrying the `N` `int`s each you needs.

The 1st allocation only allocates the row-indexing pointers.

> to access the element A[i, j] where i and j are the row and column indices starting from zero. It it possible to do it via dereferencing the pointer **

Sure, just do

```
A[1][1]
```

to access the element the 2nd element of the 2nd row.

This is identical to

```
*(*(A + 1) + 1)
```

---

*Unrelated to you question:*

Although the code you show is correct, a more robust way to code this would be:

```
int ** A = malloc(N * sizeof *A);
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++) 
{
  A[i] = malloc(N * sizeof *A[i]);
}
```

`size_t` is the type of choice for indexing, as it guaranteed to be large enough to hold any index value possible for the system the code is compiled for.

**Also you want to add error checking** to the two calls of `malloc()`, as it might return `NULL` in case of failure to allocate the amount of memory requested.

Comment: If the malloc is called from the main, I put in "if *A=NULL return EXIT_FAILURE" which terminates the execution. But how to terminate the execution indicating an error if the malloc is called from another function?

Comment: A program can be ended by calling `exit()`. @Roy

Answer (score 2):

The declaration is correct, but the matrix won't occupy continuous memory space. It is array of pointers, where each pointer can point to whatever location, that was returned by `malloc`. For that reason addressing like `(A+ni+j)` does not make sense.

Assuming that compiler has support for VLA (which became optional in C11), the idiomatic way to define continuous matrix would be:

```
int (*matrixA)[N] = malloc(N * sizeof *matrixA);
```

In general, the syntax of matrix with `N` rows and `M` columns is as follows:

```
 int (*matrix)[M] = malloc(N * sizeof *matrixA);
```

Notice that both `M` and `N` does not have to be given as constant expressions (thanks to VLA pointers). That is, they can be ordinary (e.g. automatic) variables.

Then, to access elements, you can use ordinary indice syntax like:

```
matrixA[0][0] = 100;
```

Finally, to relase memory for such matrices use single `free`, e.g.:

```
free(matrixA);
free(matrix);
```

Comment: "*in modern C*" With C11 support for VLAs became *optionally*.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand that 2D and higher arrays do not work well in C 89. Beginner books usually introduce 2D arrays in a very early chapter, just after 1D arrays, which leads people to assume that the natural way to represent 2-dimensional data is via a 2D array. In fact they have many tricky characteristics and should be considered an advanced feature.

If you don't know array dimensions at compile time, or if the array is large, it's almost always easier to allocate a 1D array and access via the logic

```
array[y*width+x];
```

so in your case, just call

```
int *A;
A  = malloc(N * N * sizeof(int))
A[3*N+2] = 123; // set element A[3][2] to 123, but you can't use this      syntax
```

It's important to note that the suggestion to use a flat array is just a suggestion, not everyone will agree with it, and 2D array handling is better in later versions of C. However I think you'll find that this method works best.